# Javascript Splitting a table into multiple tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I'm trying to have a dynamic table which is created by a incoming JSON table.

the JSON table is following the format above:

```
[timestamp, value1, value2, value3, value4]
```

the number of values is not fix, one query can return 4 values, next one 5, 6, 7...
the table comes in the table data

The code below attempt to create another table like below:

```
s[1] = [Timestamp, value1]
s[2] = [Timestamp, value2]
s[3] = [Timestamp, value3]
....
```

Here is the code

```
var s = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
    var myrow = String(data[i]);
    var l = (myrow.match(/,/g) || []).length + 1
    var myarr = myrow.split(",");

    for (var j = 1; j < l; j++){
        if (isNaN(s[j])) {
            s[j] = new Array(2);
        }
        if (parseFloat(myarr[j]) != 0){
            s[j].push([parseInt(myarr[0]), parseFloat(myarr[j])]);
        }
}
```

But when I execute this code, all my s[j] are NaN.

Here is an example of what I am expecting to get:

```
//first iteration
data = ["1413370800000", "68.400580793576", "35.854875270197", "0"]
timestamp = 1413370800000
value1 = 68.400580793576
s[1] = [1413370800000, 68.400580793576]
timestamp = 1413370800000
value2 = 35.854875270197
s[2] = [1413370800000, 35.854875270197]
timestamp = 1413370800000
value3 = 0 
s[3] = [1413370800000, 0]

//second iteration
data = ["1413356400000", "125.99187714667", "19.503481981345", "138.13301276328"]
s[1] = [[1413370800000, 68.400580793576], [1413356400000, 125.99187714667]]
s[2] = [1413370800000, 35.854875270197], [1413356400000, 19.503481981345]]
s[3] = [1413370800000, 0],  [1413356400000, 138.13301276328]]
```

can you help me ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
data = ["1413370800000", "68.400580793576", "35.854875270197", "0"]

ts = new Date(parseInt(data.shift())); // or whatever...

data2 = data.map(function(x) {
  return [ts, parseFloat(x)]; 
});
  
document.write(JSON.stringify(data2));
```

Generally, Javascript [iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) lead to simpler and more readable code than bare loops.

Comment: Thank you georg, I may not have been clear enough in my example. I have edited the example with what I'm expecting to get. but you are right I need to study this iteration methods...

Answer (score 0):

As for georg's answer, but using a for loop (and assuming you want the Strings converted to Numbers):

```
data = ["1413370800000", "68.400580793576", "35.854875270197", "0"]

for (var i=1, data2=[]; i<data.length; i++) {
  data2.push([+data[0], +data[i]]);
}
```

Comment: thank you RobG, I have edited the example to explain better what I'm expecting to get.